# How to get instance attribute name-values in a class with __slots__ in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

When defining two classes, one with the __dict__ implementation (A) and the other with __slots__ implementation (B).

Is there a clever way of getting the instance attribute **names and values** of the __slots__ class, as I would with using the vars() function on the __dict__ class?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


class B(object):
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y', 'z')
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


vars(A(1, 2, 3)) # {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
vars(B(1, 2, 3)) # TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

using .__slots__ or dir() with inspection would just return the attribute names, without the value

```
B(1, 2, 3).__slots__ # ('x', 'y', 'z')
```

Comment: You can use `getattr` to get the value of an attribute by the attribute's name as a string.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function I've used before:

```
def vars2(obj):
    try:
        return vars(obj)
    except TypeError:
       return {k: getattr(obj, k) for k in obj.__slots__}
```

Comment: Note that `__slots__` can also be assigned a string, hence direct iteration over it might not be correct all the time.

Comment: Adding to @AshwiniChaudhary, classes can have some things defined by `__slots__` and others stored in the normal `__dict__` (this can happen intentionally by making one of the `__slots__` be `'__dict__'` or accidentally if some classes in an inheritance hierarchy define `__slots__` and others don't); in that scenario, neither `vars` nor this hack will get the complete set of instance attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [2]: x = B(1,2,3)

In [3]: {a: x.__getattribute__(a) for a in dir(x)}
Out[3]: 
{'__class__': __main__.B,
 '__delattr__': <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of B object at 0x7f3bb2b48e18>,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__format__': <function __format__>,
 '__getattribute__': <method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of B object at 0x7f3bb2b48e18>,
 '__hash__': <method-wrapper '__hash__' of B object at 0x7f3bb2b48e18>,
 '__init__': <bound method B.__init__ of <__main__.B object at 0x7f3bb2b48e18>>,
 '__module__': '__main__',
 '__new__': <function __new__>,
 '__reduce__': <function __reduce__>,
 '__reduce_ex__': <function __reduce_ex__>,
 '__repr__': <method-wrapper '__repr__' of B object at 0x7f3bb2b48e18>,
 '__setattr__': <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of B object at 0x7f3bb2b48e18>,
 '__sizeof__': <function __sizeof__>,
 '__slots__': ('x', 'y', 'z'),
 '__str__': <method-wrapper '__str__' of B object at 0x7f3bb2b48e18>,
 '__subclasshook__': <function __subclasshook__>,
 'x': 1,
 'y': 2,
 'z': 3}
```

Or if you don't want to see magic methods:

```
In [4]: {a: x.__getattribute__(a) for a in dir(x) if not a.startswith('__')}
Out[4]: {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```